# Difference between "настрой" and "настроение"

Tags: значения, разница

People asked me "Как настрой"?

I thought it meant the same as "Как настроение?".

They claimed the meaning was not the same but did not really explain what was the difference (just something like "This means like "ready for fight" or sth of that sort).

Could somebody explain the difference?

Update: Maybe one could say настрой is more in the direction of "готовность к какой-нибудь (активной) деятельности"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Как настрой"?

This question can be replaced to: [Are you sure you can do it?]

> "Как настроение?"

This question can be replaced to: [How are you?]

---

> "Как настрой"?
>   "Как настроение?"

They both mean mental state, but
[настрой] goes from weak to strong
[настроение] goes from bad to good

You can not say he has bad [настрой]
You can say he has strong [настрой]

You can not say he has strong [настроение]
You can say he has good [настроение]

---

Can we say that [настрой] = [готовность к какой-нибудь (активной) деятельности]?

In someway yes, but [готовность] in Russian mean [readyness] and therefore it is much wider, than [настрой].
[настрой] can be in someway treated as [mental readyness], whereas [готовность] is more wide.

Let's take exam as example.

[готовность к экзамену] means how good you memorized material.
[настрой] means how confident you are, how you are sure in your abitility to pass exam.
[настроение] means general state of your mood, which may be different from [настрой]. You might have a strong [настрой], but your [настроение] can be bad, because your alarm clock failed to ring and you had no time to have breakfast. That is the case of strong [настрой], but bad [настроение].

There are people, who are not ready for exam, but they are sure that everything gonna be ok. Their [настрой] is strong.

There are people, who are ready for exam and study like crazy, but they are not sure that everything gonna be ok and they lack self confience. Their [настрой] is weak.

---

Usually [настрой] is the source for [настроение].

If you have strong [настрой] than it will make your [настроение] good.
If you have weak [настрой] that might result into bad [настроение].

Comment: Thanks, I think you should put the last part to the beginning, as a kind of abstract.

Answer (score 5):

*Настроение* из just about someone's **mood**, *настрой* (in its optimistic sense) is related to self-discipline: *concentrating* on some idea (going to a dentist at last - *настроил себя на это*), nearest activity (like participation in an important football game - *команда вышла с хорошим настроем на игру*) or plan (e. g. to learn a new language - *выработал в себе настрой на эту деятельность*).

Comment: Maybe one could say настрой is more like готовность к чему нибудь?

Comment: It's somehow related, but e. g. a strong team is _always ready_ to beat a weaker one and maybe even doesn't need to think about difficulties.

Comment: @wondering - _Настрой_ is a noun formed from the verb _настроить_ 'to tune [a musical instrument, a machine, a radio]', so it's like 'tuning'.

Comment: Yes, it's very much about tuning oneself, the noun being the result of that tuning.

Comment: @YellowSky Настроение is a noun formed from which verb?

Comment: @wondering - _Настроение_ is from the same verb, _настроить_, but it has the suffix _-ение_ used to form abstract nouns, so _настроение_ is more abstract and more objective than the concrete and subjective _настрой_.

Comment: The **spirit** as in "That's the spirit!" is a good analogy for the typical meaning of *настрой*.

Answer (score 0):

Настрой - это настроение, которое нужно мне для достижения определенных задач или для получения определенного результата (настрой сохраняется длительное время).

Настроение - это внутреннее, душевное состояние на данный момент времени (может меняться)